# Can't access shares after installing SP1 for Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

Just finished installing SP1 for Server 2008 R2, all went fine other than i can't access any shares using a UNC. When using \server from clients or on the server i get the following message;

```
Windows cannot access \\ntserver

Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.

Error Code: 0x80070002
The System cannot find the file specified.
```

I've also tried with the FQDN and the ip and i get the same message. I've disabled the firewalls on the server and client and still have the issue.

EDIT: also found these in the event logs, unsure if they are related;

```
The WinRM service failed to create the following SPNs: WSMAN/NTSERVER.school.local; WSMAN/NTSERVER.
```

Additional Data 
 The error received was 8344: %%8344.

User Action 
 The SPNs can be created by an administrator using setspn.exe utility.

```
The winlogon notification subscriber <GPClient> took 97 second(s) to handle the notification event (CreateSession).
```

I'm lost at what to try now!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [page](http://panerarichang.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/win2k8error-code-0x80070002-system.html)

> - Open Regedit "HKEY LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM \CurrentControISet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order"
> - The "ProviderOrder" Key has just one value for the "hgfs"
> - Validated with another server having the same configuration  the Key above and the information found were different:
> - The Key "ProvideOrder" contains: "vmhgfs,hgfs,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation"
> - Copied the value from this server to Issued Server.

Comment: Already tried that one and i'm still having the same issue. thanks